# Why there is creation of electric field from n-type to p-type in pn junction?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics

I know that in pn juction due to diffusion the electrons in the n-type semiconductor moves to p-type semiconductor, but I am confused that why electric field is developed from n type to p-type rather than ptype to n-type.

Answer (score 0):

When the electrons diffuse from n-type region to p-type region, the atoms in n-type region will lose electron, therefore giving n-type region a positive charge. The opposite happens for p-type region. Electrons that diffuse into the p-type region gives a negative charge in the region. Due to the charge difference, the electric field will develop, from positive charge to negative charge, which is from n-type to p-type.

Comment: If positive charge is created in n junction then why not the positive charge get neutral by the electrons present in n type?

Comment: That's because the amount of electron is reduced but the amount of protons stays. One way to think of this is that during diffusion, the dopant in n-type region loses electron (eg P loses 1 electron and becomes P+). Even if the electron from other P atoms moves to this P+, the other P will then become P+ instead.

Comment: Oh thanks i understood

Answer (score 0):

When a pn junction is formed, a phenomenon known as carrier drift occurs, whereby electrons and holes migrate from areas of higher concentration to those of lower concentration. Specifically, electrons traverse from the n-region to the p-region, while holes traverse from the p-region to the n-region. Prior to this diffusion, both regions were neutrally charged; however, the drift results in the loss of neutrality for each region individually. Nevertheless, the semiconductor as a whole remains electrically neutral, as the flow of charges is contained within it and has no effect outside of its boundaries. Consequently, the n-region becomes positively charged, while the p-region becomes negatively charged, generating an electric field that is from the positively charged region to the negatively charged one.

Comment: This answer was already given. You should add something new to this answer to make it useful.